# Check if variables are equal to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how you can check if variables are equal to each other. I have around 10 variables and I want to check if some of them are equal to each other, and if they are they should be in their own array

```
const user1TeamID = 2
const user2TeamID = 4
const user3TeamID = 2
const user4TeamID = 3
const user5TeamID = 1
const user6TeamID = 3
const user7TeamID = 4 ... so on
```

EDIT:

So I have 10 users that have a team, and I want to filter all users into their teams ID, so my output is an array

How can I do that?

Comment: Please explain your question with a proper example.

Comment: There are many comparison operators and methods. Show an example and use an array.

Comment: "_how you can check if variables are equal to each other_" you mean `var1 == var2`?

Comment: And what would be the output you are wanting.

Comment: You should instead store them in an object or an array of objects, then loop through it, then compare the current item to others.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to rearrange your declaration. Instead of storing `teamID` at a variable with a userID prefix, you should use an array of objects for storing your data. You can follow this structure.

```
const teams = [
  {
    teamID: 1,
    users: [1, 2, 4]
  },
  {
    teamID: 2,
    users: [3, 5, 7]
  },
  {
    teamID: 3,
    users: [6, 9]
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to learn about arrays and objects in javascript, there are planty of things you can do with them and they make things easy from the API to the front

if I were you I will do like this

1st- make an object containing all all your variables (users)

2nd- get all the unique teamIDs (teams)

3rd- group the users by the team

something like that

```js
//those are the users
let users = [
    {
        userID: 1,
        teamID: 2
    },
    {
        userID: 2,
        teamID: 4
    },
    {
        userID: 3,
        teamID: 2
    },
    {
        userID: 4,
        teamID: 3
    },
    {
        userID: 5,
        teamID: 1
    },
    {
        userID: 6,
        teamID: 3
    },
    {
        userID: 7,
        teamID: 4
    },
]

//those are the teamListId
let teamListId = [...new Set(users.map(user => user.teamID))]

//grouped users by team
teamListId.map(teamID => ({
    teamID,
    users: users.filter(user => user.teamID == teamID).map(el => el.userID)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be simply as folowing:

```
const __get = (name) => { return eval(name) };

const idList = {};

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    const name = `user${i}TeamID`, id = __get(name);
    if (idList[id] === undefined) idList[id] = [];
    idList[id].push(name);
}

console.log(idList);
```

for array type output:

```
const __get = (name) => { return eval(name) };

const idxList = {}, idArray = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    const name = `user${i}TeamID`, id = __get(name), index = idArray.length-1;
    if (idxList[id]) {
        index = idxList[id];
        idArray[index][id].push(name);
    } else {
        idxList[id] = ++index;
        idArray.push({});
        idArray[index][id] = [name];
    }
}

console.log(idArray);
```